# Trimming WSDL file manually guidelines

Tags: metadata-api, wsdl2apex, wsdl

i need to update a custom picklist field of standard object.i need to add a value when an object is inserted.i download metadata wsdl file .but its very big .and i am not getting how to trim it ??any particular guidelines for trimming .any one attempted this before ??

Answer (score 3):

**Trimming Options and Recommended Approach.** You can either trim the WSDL or trim the resulting Apex class from the WSDL2Apex tool. I recommend the later, as the Apex compiler will warn you if you delete class that is referenced more easily. Start first by removing the static methods (representing the operations from the WSDL) you don't want. Then start by commenting out the inner classes within. Again the compiler will warn you about any types still referenced by the operations (methods) you've retained for you needs. Its a slow process.

**Code Coverage Motive?** If the basis for your question is to avoid having to generate code coverage, you may find it useful to know that the [Apex Metadata API library](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) already contains a [test class](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceTest.cls) that generates 100% code coverage for the generated class, so you don't have to trim it. The approach used has also been described [here](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/05/11/code-coverage-for-wsdl2apex-generated-classes/).

Comment: not code coverage actually this library only consuming 15^% of apex and most of the code is of no use.

Comment: OK understood, Salesforce maybe able to increase your Apex code limit for your org if you contact support. Otherwise, if its just the CustomField related code, keep the create, checkAsync methods and delete all classes apart from CustomField, Metadata and stuff like AsyncResult. It maybe better to comment out aggressively and then use the compiler to tell you what to add back in!

Comment: I thought classes marked with @IsTest didn't contribute towards the Orgs Apex code limit? So while it might not be pretty to have a huge apex class for code coverage, you shouldn't be suffering for the test cases at least. The wsdl2apex class in another story.